# NGINX RTMP convert flv to hls?

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp, flv, http-live-streaming

I have a server that takes an rtmp stream and saves it as flv.

Web users can view the flv video in their browser, however iPhone users can't as it is flash

Is there away to convert the saved flv files on the fly to hls for the iPhone viewers?

here is my config, Webusers access the vod application

```
rtmp {
     server {
             listen 1935;
             chunk_size 4096;

             application live {
                     live on;
                     record all;
                     record_path /videos/av;
                     idle_streams off;
             }
             application audio {
                     live on;
                     record audio;
                     record_path /videos/audio;
                     idle_streams off;

             }
             application vod {
                     play /videos/av;
             }
             application aod {
                     play /videos/audio;
             }

     } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [nginx-rtmp-module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module), which is available for free. It takes an rtmp input and is able to create HLS.
If you don't want to use a self-managed server, you could use services like [Bitmovin's encoding service](https://www.bitmovin.com/encoding/).

Comment: Thanks, I am already using nginx-rtmp and am taking an rtmp stream and saving it as flv
however users need watch the saved flv files at a later date on their iphone in safari. 
So I was wondering how to live transcode the saved flv files to something the iphone can play

Comment: Why don't you store the HLS chunks plus an m3u8 instead of the FLV? You could also remove the FLV entirely as there are already several Flash players with HLS support available.

Comment: Its a little complicated for business reason im working with an app that sends an rtmp stream to nginx, im not specifically telling it to save flv it just seems to be saving it as flv.

I cant change the app as it is already built, so I was thinking to convert the incoming flv rtmp steam to HLS and save a HLS chunks along with the flv

So I have two versions. Can this be done?